# How to calculate the sum of integer values of an attributes in XSLT version 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to calculate the sum of attributes using xslt 1.0. below is the xml file as an input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <alltestsuites>
   <testsuite tests="2" failures="0" disabled="1" errors="0" pass="1">
     <testcase name="test1" file="abc.cpp" status="pass" />
     <testcase name="test2" file="def.cpp" status="disabled" />
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite tests="2" failures="1" disabled="1" errors="0" pass="0">
     <testcase name="test1" file="ghi.cpp" status="disabled" />
     <testcase name="test2" file="jkl.cpp" status="failure" />
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite tests="2" failures="0" disabled="2" errors="0" time="0">
     <testcase name="test1" file="jkl.cpp" status="disabled" />
     <testcase name="test2" file="mno.cpp" status="disabled" />
   </testsuite>
 </alltestsuites>
```

Basically I am trying to calculate the sum of tests, failure, disabled and error from each testsuite.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/alltestsuites/testsuite/@tests)"/>
```

AFAICT, the same result could be obtained by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/alltestsuites/testsuite/testcase)" />
```